# Expression/word for when a speaker changes during a conference

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a single word or an expression for when a different presenter starts talking in a meeting/conference?

I.e. 'The video timestamp highlighted the [change of presenters/ when someone else started presenting] during the summit.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term I would probably use for this is [***transition***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transition), modified as necessary for clarity and flow—i.e. *presenter transition* or *transition of presenters* or even *transition from one presenter to another*. This is a fairly standard usage for this situation. A few examples (all bolding added, except the first heading):

> **Transitions**
>   We typically present our content by referring to note cards, outlines, key words on slides, TelePrompTers, and other tools that prompt us to what we plan to say or do. One thing to script, however, is the **transition** statement from one topic to the next, especially when it involves a different presenter. Script each **transition** so the “from” presenter knows exactly how to introduce the “to” presenter and topic. The “to” presenter needs a **transition** statement to receive the platform so the two topics merge seamlessly.

—[Sylviah, "Smooth Transitions: Team presentations", *Springboard Training*, October 7, 2009](http://www.springboardtraining.com/topics-by-category/public-speaking/team-presentations-smooth)

> During **speaker transitions** the moderator can ask a question while the next speaker gets their PPT deck on screen and so on until the end.

—[Lee Odden, "How not to suck being a conference moderator or speaker", *Top Rank Marketing*](https://www.toprankblog.com/2010/11/moderators-speakers-conferences/)

> Make sure to work with the moderator and other presenters to ensure that the flow of the session is planned in a manner that allows a quick **transition from speaker to speaker** regardless of equipment used.

—["Presenter Information", National Women's Studies Association Annual Conference](https://www.nwsa.org/presenterinformation)

If that term is too generic, a more idiomatic, metaphorical phrase may work for you: [*passing the baton*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/baton). This term comes from relay races, where teammates literally hand over a baton when transitioning from one active racer to the next. In extended usage (from Oxford Dictionaries Online):

> **pass (on) the baton**
>   Hand over a particular duty or responsibility.
>
> **take up (or pick up) the baton**
>   Accept a particular duty or responsibility.

In the context of a multi-presenter presentation, this phrase should be fairly clear. It isn't nearly as commonplace as *transition*, but here are a couple of examples in context:

> One of the least-practiced aspects of the group presentation is how you **pass the baton** – the **transition between speakers**. Yet these **baton-passing** linkages within your presentation are incredibly important.

—[Stanley K. Ridgley, "How to transition between speakers", *Business School Presentations*, March 26, 2014](https://www.ihatepresentations.com/how-to-transition-between-speakers/) (I note that the caption on this article's illustration claims that "*How to **transition between speakers** is the most-searched term on this site.*")

> I presented last, so I got to watch the other presenters. It wasn’t pretty. The guy before me (let’s call him Rock) was especially bad—he had a 20-minute time slot and a 50-slide deck. . . . Finally, Rock finished his deck and **passed me the metaphorical baton**.

—[Mark Murphy, "How To Stop A Presentation That's Going Badly", *Forbes*, Mar 3, 2015](https://www.forbes.com/sites/markmurphy/2015/03/03/how-to-stop-a-presentation-thats-going-badly/#4467940e6f01)